# Cant change / edit splash screen and xml files in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

So i'm trying to change my starting splash screen from the basic white when starting up the application but whenever i;m trying to edit it to another color or to another picture I seem to not be able to change it, it stays red, is it because i'm missing a setting or something? pic below also shows that i've added the picture i'm trying to add. Please help i've been stuck at this for 2 hours

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to run the app? If you edit these data in the Flutter project, many things are red. Try to open it as android project to see if it is still red... or just try to run the app

Comment: of course i've tried running the app its just the default white splash screen, i've also tried just changing the color to black and it still stays white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also make the same change in the folder drawable-v21

Comment: oh my goodness i cant believe this worked hahaha thank you so much! I couldnt find this anywhere